# Скачать файл поле ввода пароля

Tags: html, javascript, php

Нужно на html сделать скачивание файла после ввода пароля.
Всё бы ничего, но пароль должен быть рандомный, либо браться из базы

Вот сам рандом на php:

```
$key = rand(50000,99999);
```

Тоесть, если введённый пользователем пароль, к примеру, 66666, то он получит ссылку на скачивание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читаем про формирование временной ссылки к файлам [тыц 1](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8+php&oq=php+cjplfybt+dhtvtyyjq+ccskrb+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i64l2.7843j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Дополнение:
При формировании страницы с формой ввода пароля на php создайте $_SESSION['password'] в неё запишите сгенерированый пароль. После отправки формы сверяйте

```
if($_SESSION['password'] == $_POST['password']){
   пароль правильный отдаём ссылку на скачивание
}
else{
   пароль неправильный снова выводим форму ввода пароля. Для лучшей безопасности по новой генерим $_SESSION['password']
};
```

Comment: Совсем не то, что нужно.

Comment: @Rammsteinik, так объясните людям, что вам нужно и в чём проблема.

Answer (score 2):

А в чем сложность-то? Создайте в базе таблицу с полями user_id и secret_key, при запросе скачивания отправляйте юзеру пароль по емейл или каким-либо другим способом, более подходящим вам, а при вводе проверяйте перед выдачей ссылки пароль:

```
if($_REQUEST['key'] === $data_base_result['secret_key']) {
    // Отдайте ему ссылку на скачивание
}
```